# Простейший скрипт рандома на php. Промежуток чисел

Tags: php

Есть промежуток чисел от [1; 100]. Нужно чтобы php выводил на экран через echo рандомные числа из этого промежутка, но так, чтобы они не повторялись, то есть, если, допустим, php зарандомил число 57, то в дальнейшем php рандомил числа в промежутке от [1;57)V(57;100] (то есть число 57 больше не повторялось)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самая элеметная реализация

```
$nums = []; 

for($i = 0; $i < 15; ;){
    $num = mt_rand(1, 100); 

    if(!in_array($num, $nums)){ 
        $nums[$i] = $num; 
        $i++;
        echo $num;
    }
}
```

Данный скрипт выведет 15 раз числа в диапазоне от 1 до 100 каждый раз исключая все прошедшие выпавшие числа, за счёт того, что сохраняет их в массиве и в дальнейшем проверяет, если ли в массиве каждое новое рандомное число, если есть, повторяем и так до тех пор пока оно не будет уникальное, когда число оказалось уникальным, сохраняем его в массиве и выводим.

Для сохранения между сессиями браузеров, поместите в `$_SESSION` массив  `nums`. Пример:

```
session_start();

//...

$_SESSION['nums'] = []; 

for($i = 0; $i < 15; ;){
    $num = mt_rand(1, 100); 

    if(!in_array($num, $_SESSION['nums'])){ 
        $_SESSION['nums'][$i] = $num; 
        $i++;
        echo $num;
    }
}
```

Comment: Задачу не читали вы, где вы видели чтобы человек что-то говорил о перезапуске скрипта? Не продумывайте решения себе на руку. :)

Comment: Совершенно верно, этого мало. В начале речь шла о выводе «на экран», о браузере как о таковом, речи не шло.

Answer (score 2):

Для примера привел готовый массив исключений. Его можно хранить в удобном для вас виде (БД, файле, Куках или сессиях), чтобы после перезагрузки страницы он был доступен и добавлялись новые элементы массива в него. После выполнения скрипта нужно снова сохранить этот массив.

```
<?php

$toRange = 100;
// Загружаем массив исключений
// Выбирай способ хранения удобный для себя - БД, файл JSON
$ex = json_decode(file_get_contents('exclude'), true);

// Проверяешь, чтобы цикл в бесконечное зацикливание не ушел
if (count($ex) <= $toRange) {
    do {
        $rand = rand(1, $toRange);
    } while (in_array($rand, $ex));
    array_push($ex, $rand); // Добавляем новое случайное число в массив исключений
    // Здесь сохраняешь массив $ex в БД или файл JSON
    file_put_contents('exclude', json_encode($ex));
    echo $rand;
} else {
    // Если диапазон допустимых элементов массива закончен
    echo 'The range is over';
}
```

Comment: Почитайте описание и комментарии в коде ) Ясно написал что привел пример готового массива, а сохранять массив можно на его усмотрение )

Answer (score 0):

Ещё можно так *(в три строчки кода, проще уже некуда)*:

1. Сгенерировать временный массив
2. Перемешать его элементы
3. Выбрать *(к примеру)* 15 элементов - все они будут случайными

Пример:

```
$arr = range(1, 100);
shuffle($arr);
$arr = array_slice($arr, 0, 15);

var_dump($arr);
```